# Should we really pay undue attention to the "language" or the decor of the questions asked?

Tags: discussion, questions, behavior, english

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [We need to help non-english-speakers somehow…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8162/we-need-to-help-non-english-speakers-somehow)
>   [What’s the correct response to poorly-phrased questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19280/whats-the-correct-response-to-poorly-phrased-questions)

Apologies if this has already been discussed in some other form in this site.

If you see a question with a "not-so-perfect" language/expression/description, would you immediately downvote/vote for closure? Or would you take the trouble to stretch a bit and try to understand the question contextually (it is indeed possible - I have seen some veterans here post graceful answers despite minimal data - they probably use the meta-data/tags/error messages and such to understand the question better, while refraining from making any negative comments whatsoever on the questioner's limitation with the language). 
But at times I see the opposite happening and I want to know if being too quick to judge someone based on their language/expression might not seriously discourage any knowledge sharing and even growth for anyone who may not have english as the first language.

Afterall this is a knowledge-sharing site, not a language forum. Is the annoyance and short fuse justified?

Looking forward to hear opinions.

Comment: While searching for the dupe: If you can't edit the answer, leave a comment that the questions needs some edits. If nothing happens, downvote it as being unclear.

Comment: Here is the dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19280/whats-the-correct-response-to-poorly-phrased-questions

Comment: I have a question/answer dyslexia: Should be "If you can't edit the question..."

Comment: @Smithers Just call everything a post, makes it so much easier.

Comment: @random: Sometimes you have to distinguish between posts and posts...

Comment: oops. it IS a duplicate. So sorry - my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You've only been a member for 13 days (judging by your profile)

**WRONG!** *I'm sorry about that*. I think I must have looked at your profile on MSO by mistake.

But you must be a saint if you don't feel the frustrations caused by poorly-worded questions.

This is certainly not a language site, but the difficulty of answering technical questions is multiplied when we can't understand the question.

There's no solution to this problem.

Comment: Their profile on SO says 9 months.

Comment: @random: thanks. Been a member for 9 months - not a super achiever profile I admit :-) but still.. i think its enough time to make the observation and open a discussion. ;-). It seems its already been discussed though although I didnt find it the first time.